# To retrieve a value in a Promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I have a method like this, and I want to fill `teamMems` array. What am I doing so wrong!

```
takeTeamMembers(client:any, teamIds:string[], projectId:string){
        
    var teamMems :TeamMember[] = []
    teamIds.forEach((teamId:string) =>{
        client.getTeamMembersWithExtendedProperties(projectId, teamId, undefined, undefined).then(
            function(items:any){
                items.map((curr:any) => {
                    if(teamMems.filter((item:TeamMember) => {return item.memberId == curr.identity.id}).length == 0){
                        teamMems= [...teamMems, {teamIds: [teamId], memberId:curr.identity.id, name:curr.identity.displayName}]
                    }
                    else{
                        teamMems.filter((item:TeamMember)=> item.memberId == curr.identity.id)[0].teamIds.push(teamId);
                    }
                })
                console.log("1 return innermems", teamMems)
            });
            console.log("2 return ", teamMems)
        })
        console.log("before return ", teamMems)
        return teamMems;
}
```

Console output is

[image]

Comment: you need to await the async function that you have. the function is returning before the async reaches the then callback you have

Comment: In particular, you're spawning asynchronous tasks within `teamIds.forEach()`, not waiting for them to return.

Comment: It's also super hard to try and understand what your code should be doing in the first place, what with the `innerMems` stuff happening within the async callback.

Comment: @AKX I clarified it as discarded `innnerMems`, by the way thanks again for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have a better time with an `async` function like this. The idea is to use `Promise.all()` to first await for all of the `getTeamMembersWithExtendedProperties` calls, and then just work on the flat, regular array.

```
// dummy implementation to ensure types are correct, replace with your actual stuff
async function getTeamMembersWithExtendedProperties(projectId: string, teamId: string) {
  return ["something"];
}

async function takeTeamMembers(client: any, teamIds: string[], projectId: string) {
  const teamsAndMembers = await Promise.all(
    teamIds.map(async (teamId) => ({
      teamId,
      members: await getTeamMembersWithExtendedProperties(projectId, teamId),
    })),
  );
  const teamMems = [];
  const innerMems = [];
  teamsAndMembers.forEach(({ teamId, members }) => {
    // Do the innerMems/teamMems logic here...
  });
  return teamMems;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

your async call needs to be awaited before it returns. Like this...

```
takeTeamMembers(client:any, teamIds:string[], projectId:string){
        
    var teamMems :TeamMember[] = []
    var innerMems : TeamMember[] = []

    // make function callback async here

    teamIds.forEach(async (teamId:string) => {
        // then await this function here
        await client.getTeamMembersWithExtendedProperties(projectId, teamId, undefined, undefined).then(
            function(items:any){
                items.map((curr:any) => {
                    if(innerMems.filter((item:TeamMember) => {return item.memberId == curr.identity.id}).length == 0){
                        innerMems = [...innerMems, {teamIds: [teamId], memberId:curr.identity.id, name:curr.identity.displayName}]
                    }
                    else{
                        innerMems.filter((item:TeamMember)=> item.memberId == curr.identity.id)[0].teamIds.push(teamId);
                    }
                })
                teamMems = teamMems.concat(innerMems)
                console.log("1 return innermems ", teamMems)
            });
            console.log("2 return ", teamMems)
        })
        console.log("before return ", teamMems)
        return teamMems;
}
```

EDIT 2:

Made the fixes for this call

```
async function takeTeamMembers(client:any, teamIds:string[], projectId:string){

    let teamMems :TeamMember[] = []
    let innerMems : TeamMember[] = []

    // remember to await the map call also
    await Promise.all(await teamIds.map(async (teamId:string) => {
        await client.getTeamMembersWithExtendedProperties(projectId, teamId, undefined, undefined).then(
            (items:any) => {
                items.map((curr:any) => {
                    if(innerMems.filter((item:any) => {return item.memberId == curr.identity.id}).length == 0){
                        innerMems = [...innerMems, {teamIds: [teamId], memberId:curr.identity.id, name:curr.identity.displayName}]
                    }
                    else{
                        innerMems.filter((item:any)=> item.memberId == curr.identity.id)[0].teamIds.push(teamId);
                    }
                })
                teamMems = teamMems.concat(innerMems);
            });
    }));

    return teamMems;
}
```

Comment: This won't work since an `async` function returns a promise, and they're not awaited by `forEach`.

Comment: I see what you mean, let me make the adjustment @AKX